# how to implement a listbox with " Add / Remove" buttons using asp.net mvc and jquery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Currently i have the following partial view which list all the available users and a "Add User to Class" link beside each user to register a user in a class:-

```
@model IEnumerable<Elearning.Models.User>
<tr>
    <th>
        Student ID
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr >
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID)
        </td>
        <td id = "userclass">
              @Ajax.ActionLink("Add User to Class", "Register", "User", new { id = item.UserID, classid = ViewBag.id },
                  new AjaxOptions { 
                      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                      HttpMethod = "POST",
                      UpdateTargetId = "incrementadd"
               })
         </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The action method which will be called when clicking on the "Add User to Class" link is:-

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public PartialViewResult Register(string id, int classid)
{
    try
    {
       //Update code here
       User user = r.FindUser(id);
       Users_Classes uc = new Users_Classes();
       uc.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
       uc.ClassID = classid;
       user.Users_Classes.Add(uc);
       r.Save();
       ViewBag.classid = classid;
       return PartialView("_usersearch2", uc);
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine , but i find it not easy to add each user by clicking on the link.
So i am trying to add a listbox with a add/remove buttons to register and unregister user based on user selection, but i can not figure out how i can modify my code to implement the listbox with "Add/Remove" button using Jquery to make my system more user friendly.
can anyone refer me to helping materials or sample code which can help me in my development?
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

For simple multi selects I am using this jquery plugin:

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Then on your view just add something like this to your form:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.YourCollectionProperty, MyRepository.FetchPropertySelectList().ToList())
```

Very straightforward and easy to use.

If you need any more help or advice on how to implement let me know.

Comment: thanks for the reply ut i am trying to implement something similat to the following http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/transferring-data-from-one-listbox-to-another-in-wpf/Images/LeftListBoxImg2.jpg